# Is there a way to insert page break using VBA in Excel based on a change in column value, but start AFTER the header?

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried the two below. Both work perfectly, except it causes there to be a page with just the headers because the value in the selected column changes from the header value to the first actual value.

Option 1:

```
    Dim I As Long, J As Long
    J = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = J To 2 Step -1
    If Range("b" & I).Value <> Range("b" & I - 1).Value Then
    ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Range("b" & I)
    End If
    Next I
```

Option 2:

```
    Dim rangeSelection As Range
    Dim cellCurrent As Range

    Set rangeSelection = Application.Selection.Columns(2).Cells
    ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks

    For Each cellCurrent In rangeSelection
    If (cellCurrent.Row > 2) Then
    If (cellCurrent.Value <> cellCurrent.Offset(-1, 0).Value) Then
    ActiveSheet.Rows(cellCurrent.Row).PageBreak = _
    xlPageBreakManual
    End If
    End If
    Next cellCurrent
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1  (assumes `ws` is already Set)

```vb
Dim I As Long, J As Long
J = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
For I = J To 2 Step -1
    If ws.Range("b" & I).Value <> ws.Range("b" & I - 1).Value Then
        ws.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ws.Range("b" & I)
    End If
Next I
```

Option 2 (assuming `ws` is set as in Option 1)

```vb
Dim rangeSelection As Range
Dim cellCurrent As Range

Set rangeSelection = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
ws.ResetAllPageBreaks

For Each cellCurrent In rangeSelection
    If cellCurrent.Row > 2 Then
        If cellCurrent.Value <> cellCurrent.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
            ws.Rows(cellCurrent.Row).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        End If
    End If
Next cellCurrent
```